# Hearing Kiddush for Shabbos and Yom Tov when for you it's just Shabbos

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, chutz-laaretz, kiddush

An Israeli is visiting the Diaspora for a holiday beginning on Friday.

On Friday night a local Diasporan will says kiddush for the holiday and shabbos. Can the Israeli, for whom it's not a holiday, fulfill his obligation for kiddush of shabbos by listening in?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Nathan and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Note that practical questions should be asked to your rabbi. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: There's a parallel question when first day Yom Tov is Shabbat, if the Israeli can fulfill havdala through Yaknehaz.

Answer (score 1):

Fantastic question. See Piskei Teshuvos ch496 section 19 part 3 where he quotes numerous authorities who discuss this, with three different options. All references can be found in fn 129-131.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! A short summary of the views would be helpful.